# Correct way to link Tasks together when return values are needed at different times #2

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, task-parallel-library, task

[I asked a question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31730391/1693085) and, unfortunately, even with the answers provided, I'm still hitting up on stumbling blocks about how to do things correctly... My issue is that my code actually works, but I'm a complete novice at concurrency programming and it feels like I'm not programming the correct way and, most importantly, I'm afraid of developing bad habits.

To make up a simplistic example to elaborate on yesterday's question, suppose I had the following methods:

```
static Task<IEnumerable<MyClass>> Task1(CancellationToken ct)

static Task<IEnumerable<int>> Task2(CancellationToken ct, List<string> StringList)

static Task<IEnumerable<String>> Task3(CancellationToken ct)

static Task<IEnumerable<Double>> Task4(CancellationToken ct)

static Task Task5(CancellationToken ct, IEnumerable<int> Task2Info, IEnumerable<string> Task3Info, IEnumerable<double> Task4Info)

static Task Task6(CancellationToken ct, IEnumerable<int> Task2Info, IEnumerable<MyClass> Task1Info)
```

And the code I've written that utilizes them looks as follows:

```
static Task execute(CancellationToken ct)
{
    IEnumerable<MyClass> Task1Info = null;
    List<string> StringList = null;
    IEnumerable<int> Task2Info = null;
    IEnumerable<string> Task3Info = null;
    IEnumerable<double> Task4Info = null;

    var TaskN = Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        Task1Info = Task1(ct).Result;
                    }
                    , ct)
                    .ContinueWith(res =>
                    {
                        StringList = Task1Info.Select(k=> k.StringVal).ToList();
                        Task2Info = Task2(ct, StringList).Result;
                    }
                    , ct);

    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return Task.WhenAll
            (
                TaskN,
                Task.Run(() => { Task3Info = Task3(ct).Result; }, ct),
                Task.Run(() => { Task4Info = Task4(ct).Result; }, ct)
            )
            .ContinueWith(res =>
            {
                Task5(ct, Task2Info, Task3Info, Task4Info).Wait();
            }
            , ct)
            .ContinueWith(res =>
            {
                Task6(ct, Task2Info, Task1Info).Wait();
            }
            , ct);
    });
}
```

**In other words:**

- I need the results of `Task1` to calculate `StringList` and to run `Task2`
- `Task2`, `Task3` and `Task4` can all run concurrently
- I need the return values from all of the above for later method calls
- Once these are run, I use their results to run `Task5`
- Once `Task5` is run, I use all the results in running `Task6`

As a simple explanation, imagine the first portion is data gathering, the second is data cleansing and the third data reporting

Like I said, my challenge is that this actually runs, but I simply feel that it's more of a "hack" that the right way to program - Concurrency programming is very new to me and I definitely want to learn the best ways this should be done...

Comment: So you're asking how to return values from the tasks?

Comment: Not necessarily how to return values from tasks, but more to the point how to store specific values from `Task1` that continues with `Task2` (that uses some other values from `Task1` (and then use them in `Task3`) - If you follow the sample code I put up, maybe that'll make more sense.

Comment: You can return values from tasks, and pick them up later.. such as https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537613(v=vs.110).aspx so you could run task1, return the list, pick it up, continue with running 3 tasks that all return values, as required.. once complete, continue with task5, then run task6 using as many or as little as you needed?

Comment: @BugFinder, I think that's exactly what I'm looking for - Between that and usr's answer below, I'm going to try and re-write the code and see if it works... Thank you!!!

Comment: Goodo, ive used this a fair bit, running a couple of setup tasks, and then running a number of tasks on the output, usually data verifying such a finding where data needs work, so duplicate ips in a list of servers, things not conforming to some arbitrary standard  etc. dump out the results of data to correct.  My code would have been similar to @usr's

Answer (score 3):

I would feel better about my answer if I could see how your `TaskN` methods were implemented. Specifically, I would want to validate the need for your `TaskN` method calls to be wrapped inside calls to `Task.Run()` if they are already returning a `Task` return value.

But personally, I would just use the `async-await` style of programming. I find it fairly easy to read/write. Documentation can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

I would then envision your code looking something like this:

```
static async Task execute(CancellationToken ct)
{
    // execute and wait for task1 to complete.
    IEnumerable<MyClass> Task1Info = await Task1(ct);

    List<string> StringList = Task1Info.Select(k=> k.StringVal).ToList();

    // start tasks 2 through 4
    Task<IEnumerable<int>> t2 = Task2(ct, StringList);
    Task<IEnumerable<string>> t3 = Task3(ct);
    Task<IEnmerable<Double>> t4 = Task4(ct);

    // now that tasks 2 to 4 have been started,
    // wait for all 3 of them to complete before continuing.
    IEnumerable<int> Task2Info = await t2;
    IEnumerable<string> Task3Info = await t3;
    IEnumerable<Double> Task4Info = await t4;

    // execute and wait for task 5 to complete
    await Task5(ct, Task2Info, Task3Info, Task4Info);

    // finally, execute and wait for task 6 to complete
    await Task6(ct, Task2Info, Task1Info);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand the code in question but it is very easy to link tasks by dependency. Example:

```
var t1 = ...;
var t2 = ...;
var t3 = Task.WhenAll(t1, t2).ContinueWith(_ => RunT3(t1.Result, t2.Result));
```

You can express an arbitrary dependency DAG like that. This also makes it unnecessary to store into local variables, although you can do that if you need.

That way you also can get rid of the awkward `Task.Run(() => { Task3Info = Task3(ct).Result; }, ct)` pattern. This is equivalent to `Task3(ct)` except for the store to the local variable which probably should not exist in the first place.

```
.ContinueWith(res =>
        {
            Task5(ct, Task2Info, Task3Info, Task4Info).Wait();
        }
```

This probably should be

```
.ContinueWith(_ => Task5(ct, Task2Info, Task3Info, Task4Info)).Unwrap()
```

Does that help? Leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you, @usr, it does help! - I'm going to try changing things like this now / over this weekend and will definitely get back to you, but thank you so much for your help and patience in explaining!!!!

Comment: I truly do apologize and have tried to figure this out myself - If you could **PLEASE** even just show me how you would code my above example specifically... My toughest challenge is the part where I define `TaskN` which has `StringList` requiring `Task1`'s result and `Task2` requiring `StringList` THEN I want that to run concurrently with `Task3` and `Task4`... I just have ZERO CLUE how to do this....

Comment: I know you absolutely do not need extra points and that they mean nothing at all anyways, but that's all I have to offer - I would **HAPPILY** offer you a bounty to see how you would actually code my specific scenario.... I'm just stuck and don't know how to do this....

Comment: @JohnBustos I would take a pass on that but I'm happy to help you with any specific problems you might have. You can do yourself a great service if you understand this problem enough to do it yourself.; I think sstan has actually coded this up in an elegant way. The only improvement I'd make there is to insert `await Task.WhenAll(t2, t3, t4)` to get better error behavior in case `t2` errors out.

Comment: Thank you so much, @usr - When I asked the other 2 solutions weren't present yet... Now I have substantially more meat to stick my teeth into. I truly appreciate your help and time and think this gives me enough to give ti a good go and come back with more questions if need be. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 2):

> it feels like I'm not programming the correct way and, most importantly, I'm afraid of developing bad habits.
>
> I definitely want to learn the best ways this should be done...

First, distinguish between *asynchronous* and *parallel*, which are two different forms of *concurrency*. An operation is a good match for "asynchronous" if it doesn't need a thread to do its work - e.g., I/O and other logical operations where you *wait for* something like timers. "Parallelism" is about splitting up CPU-bound work across multiple cores - you need parallelism if your code is maxing out one CPU at 100% and you want it to run faster by using other CPUs.

Next, follow a few guidelines for which APIs are used in which situations. `Task.Run` is for pushing CPU-bound work to other threads. If your work isn't CPU-bound, you shouldn't be using `Task.Run`. `Task<T>.Result` and `Task.Wait` are even more on the parallel side; with few exceptions, they should really only be used for [dynamic task parallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963551.aspx). Dynamic task parallelism is extremely powerful (as @usr pointed out, you can represent any DAG), but it's also low-level and awkward to work with. There are almost always better approaches. `ContinueWith` is another example of an API that is for dynamic task parallelism.

Since your method signatures return `Task`, I'm going to assume that they're naturally asynchronous (meaning: they don't use `Task.Run`, and are probably implemented with I/O). In that case, `Task.Run` is the incorrect tool to use. The proper tools for asynchronous work are the `async` and `await` keywords.

So, taking your desired behavior one at a time:

```
// I need the results of Task1 to calculate StringList and to run Task2
var task1Result = await Task1(ct);
var stringList = CalculateStringList(task1Result);

// Task2, Task3 and Task4 can all run concurrently
var task2 = Task2(ct, stringList);
var task3 = Task3(ct);
var task4 = Task4(ct);
await Task.WhenAll(task2, task3, task4);

// I need the return values from all of the above for later method calls
var task2Result = await task2;
var task3Result = await task3;
var task4Result = await task4;

// Once these are run, I use their results to run Task5
await Task5(ct, task2Result, task3Result, task4Result);

// Once Task5 is run, I use all the results in running Task6
await Task6(ct, task2Result, task1Result);
```

For more about what APIs are appropriate in which situations, I have a [Tour of Task](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html) on my blog, and I cover a lot of concurrency best practices in [my book](http://stephencleary.com/book/).